# Image button concatenated variable gives undefined error

Tags: javascript, html

I have an ever growing program, in which I use concatenated html code, the variable is neatly put where i want it, (lines below):

```
var imginput =  "<input type='image' onclick='myFunction("
var imginput1 = ")' onmouseover='imgnw(this)' onmouseout='imgpic(this)' WIDTH='32' HEIGHT='32' BORDER='0' value='"
```

this (below) is the concatenation of the variables, all works fine, in by right of the error box I get with the onclick event, my variable is neatly nested between the brackets.

```
expressie = (imginput+tdid1+imginput1+tdid1+"' "+vectorwhite+afsluiter1 );
```

The error I get is a message undefined, since screen vectors i need the function onclick to pass to `function myFunction(tabloc)`  ... tdid1 = the variable that shows in the error box, so the string is there, whichever location i click on, but it never reaches myFunction (below)

```
//function myFunction(tabloc) {
//(startloc == "0")
//  {startloc = tabloc;

//  }

//}


myFunction = function (tabloc){
    startloc = tabloc;
    d.write(startloc);
}
```

I tried both, the remarked version and the one in the script as other variations. Problem is the immensity of the script, I can easely write a sepperate script, for this part, but I will stumble then on the fact that I stil need the code in the old script wich works fine.

So how do i get my variable into the variable `(startloc)`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put a string in the Javascript code you need to put string delimiters (apostrophes or quotation marks) around it:

```
var imginput =  "<input type='image' onclick='myFunction(\"";
var imginput1 = "\")' onmouseover='imgnw(this)' onmouseout='imgpic(this)' WIDTH='32' HEIGHT='32' BORDER='0' value='";
```

Note: This only takes care of the syntax error. If the string contains backslashes or the delimiter, those have to be escaped. Also, if the string contains the characters `<`, `>`, `&` or the attribute delimiter (apostrophes in your code) those needs to be HTML encoded.

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution was the answer, it sparked enough to more easely find the solution, vectors now pass into the myfunction from allover the screen with the right coordinates. No doubt I have characters running around from start to next position soon. (Or Whatever) The main proble though was that I had "'" before myfunction and after the closing bracket in the 2nd variable! Cannot vote you, lol, missing 4 points on my reputation it seams. But thanks again for resetting my train of thought to a possible syntax error